# Check route is present in navigation stack

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a scenario where I want to check if the Home screen is present in NavigatorStack if yes

```
navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(RouteUtil.ROUTE_HOME));
```

else

```
Don't pop as it shows a black screen when pops, How can I check if this exists or not?
```